# How to Count Number of Cells with Specific Month and Color

Tags: excel

I think I had a look everywhere for this.

My problem is following:

I want to have number of completed jobs (GREEN) and not completed (RED) for each month.

Can this be done ?

See image below for my setup.

[image: table]

Comment: Can you give some more context? What are "cells"? Are you working with a spreadsheet? Or an HTML table?

Comment: Can you see the picture attached?

Comment: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500861927322

Comment: See attached link.